# Example of sets $A$ and $B$ and functions $F$ and $G$ such that $F: A \rightarrow B, G: B \rightarrow A, G \circ F = I_{A}$, and $G \neq F^{-1}$

Tags: functions, inverse, function-and-relation-composition

Give an example of sets $A$ and $B$ and functions $F$ and $G$ such that $F: A \rightarrow B, G: B \rightarrow A, G \circ F = I_{A}$, and $G \neq F^{-1}$

I was thinking maybe $F$ can be a function whose inverse does not exist. Say $F(x) = x^{2}$. And $G(x) = \sqrt{x}$, then $G \circ F = x$, but $G \neq F^{-1}$. Does this work out? And $A$ could just be $\left \{1,2 \right \}$ and $B = \left \{1, 4 \right \}$.

Comment: If you let $A$ be a one-element set and let $B$ be any set with more than one element, the *any* functions $F:A\to B$ and $G:B\to A$ provide an example of the sort you want.

Answer (score 2):

Your initial thought was correct, but the example you gave wasn't.

$F(x) = x^2$  doesn't have an inverse on $\mathbb R$, but on the $A$ and $B$ you defined, it does! In your example $G \circ F = \operatorname{id}_A$ as you wanted, but $G = F^{-1}$ **does** hold because on the restricted domains $A$ and $B$, $F$ **is** invertible.

Here's a simple example: Let $A = \{a\}$ and $B = \{1, 2\}$. Define $F : A \to B$ by $F(a) = 1$ and $G : B \to A$ by $G(1) = G(2) = a$. Observe that $G \circ F = \operatorname{id}_A$ since $G(F(a)) = G(1) = a$. But $F^{-1}$ is not defined on $B$ since there is no element of $A$ such that it maps to $b$, that is, $F$ is not surjective. Since $F^{-1}$ doesn't exist, it can't be equal to $G$.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the function $f:k[X]\to k[X]$ that sends a polynomial $p$ to its derivative $p'$ and the function $g$ that sends a polynomial $p$ to the unique polynomial $P$ for which $P(0)=0$ and $P'=p$. Then $fg(p)=p$ but $gf(p)=p-p(0)$.